# Why is my Mac using smb://IP-address in File Sharing

Tags: macos, catalina, smb

I have a weird situation.

One of my Macs is file sharing, its hostname and local hostname are set but in  System Preferences > Sharing > File Sharing the address to access the SMB share is given as `smb://<IP-address>`. However on other Macs in my network it's `smb://<hostname>`.

Where does Mac OS get this value from?

I've used the `scutil --get HostName` and `... LocalHostName` command.
I've looked in /Library/Preference/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.smb.server.plist

I have looked in the file /etc/hosts.

What am I missing?

Comment: If it works on other Macs, the problem isn't the server, it's something to do with the client. The first thing I would look at is your DNS setup, the Bonjour (mDNSResponder), firewalls, etc.

Comment: Local dns has three entries for web-servers that are port forwarded into from outside.

Comment: mDNSResponder:  I did a dns-sd -B _smb and the machines show up with their hostnames under the instanced names column

Comment: What firewall settings would block this I'm not that knowledgeable in that regard

Comment: It would block DNS or NetBIOS.  Given that it's the IP and not the name, DNS would play a role here.